# Save $_REQUEST variable as a constant

Tags: php, request

```
$_SESSION['guess1']=$_REQUEST['name'];
```

I'm trying to save that variable for my first guess for my mini hangman game, but whenever I put another input in, it changes. How could I save the request variable as a constant?

Comment: If you assign a new value to a variable it overwrites it. It sounds like you need to assign new values to new variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
session_start();

if( !isset( $_SESSION['guesses'] )) {
    $_SESSION['guesses'] = array(
        $_REQUEST['name'];
    );
} else {
    $_SESSION['guesses'][] = $_REQUEST['name'];
}
```

This will create the $_SESSION['guesses'] array such that $_SESSION['guesses'][0] will contain the first guess, $_SESSION['guesses'][1] will contain the second, and so on.  Also, `count( $_SESSION['guesses'] );` will give you the total number of guesses made.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['firstGuess'])) {                 // if firstguess not already set
    $_SESSION['firstGuess'] = $_REQUEST['name'];       // set it. 
} else {
    // second and subsequent guess code here.
}
```